# Integrated webcam doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04 Dell Inspiron 13

Tags: dell, webcam, inspiron

I have my Dell Inspiron 13 with Ubuntu 18.04 installed. My integrated webcam doesn’t work with zoom, Google Meeting, Microsoft Team, skype or with any such app. It used to work about 3 months before. I don’t remember now, what I have done to my laptop in between. I don’t know, what information help. But, I am listing below what I have tried. Any help will be appreciated. Nothing seems to be blocking the webcam physically.

1. On trying with cheese, it shows a black screen with error: No device found
2. On trying with guvcview, I get the following error on terminal:

```
GUVCVIEW: version 2.0.5
GUVCVIEW: couldn't open /home/bsarma/.config/guvcview2/video0 for read: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: ERROR opening V4L interface: No such file or directory
GUVCVIEW (1): Guvcview error
     no video device found

(guvcview:6035): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:47:40.052: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:17: not a number

(guvcview:6035): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:47:40.052: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:31: Using Pango syntax for the font: style property is deprecated; please use CSS syntax

(guvcview:6035): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:47:40.052: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:17: not a number

(guvcview:6035): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:47:40.052: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:32: Using Pango syntax for the font: style property is deprecated; please use CSS syntax
Gtk-Message: 16:47:40.063: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
```

3. output of lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 27c6:5301  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c542 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

4. output of lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1e.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO UART Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:1e.4 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d2b (rev 21)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Intel(R) 100 Series Chipset Family LPC Controller/eSPI Controller - 9D4E (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 79)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Toshiba America Info Systems Device 0113 (rev 01)
```

5. output of ls /dev/video*

```
ls: cannot access '/dev/video*': No such file or directory
```

6. output of v4l2-ctl --list-devices

```
Failed to open /dev/video0: No such file or directory
```

7. output of lsmod

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 81920  16
pci_stub               16384  1
vboxpci                24576  0
vboxnetadp             28672  0
vboxnetflt             28672  0
vboxdrv               479232  3 vboxpci,vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt
ccm                    20480  9
bnep                   24576  2
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  1
hid_multitouch         28672  0
8250_dw                16384  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek   131072  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
snd_hda_intel          49152  6
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  1 snd_hda_intel
mei_hdcp               24576  0
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
snd_hda_core           90112  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
dell_laptop            20480  0
snd_pcm               102400  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
ledtrig_audio          16384  3 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek,dell_laptop
dell_smm_hwmon         20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    20480  0
intel_powerclamp       20480  0
coretemp               20480  0
kvm_intel             253952  0
kvm                   659456  1 kvm_intel
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
aesni_intel           372736  6
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
btusb                  57344  0
cryptd                 24576  2 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
rapl                   20480  0
i915                 1982464  31
intel_cstate           20480  0
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
dell_wmi               20480  0
btintel                24576  1 btusb
iwlmvm                385024  0
dell_smbios            28672  2 dell_wmi,dell_laptop
dcdbas                 20480  1 dell_smbios
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
input_leds             16384  0
snd_timer              36864  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
bluetooth             544768  43 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
mac80211              856064  1 iwlmvm
joydev                 28672  0
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
snd                    86016  23 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
serio_raw              20480  0
cdc_acm                40960  0
drm_kms_helper        188416  1 i915
ecc                    32768  1 ecdh_generic
dell_wmi_descriptor    20480  2 dell_wmi,dell_smbios
wmi_bmof               16384  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
drm                   491520  18 drm_kms_helper,i915
iwlwifi               339968  1 iwlmvm
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
intel_lpss_pci         20480  0
mei_me                 40960  1
processor_thermal_device    24576  0
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
ucsi_acpi              16384  0
intel_lpss             16384  1 intel_lpss_pci
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
typec_ucsi             40960  1 ucsi_acpi
intel_rapl_common      24576  2 intel_rapl_msr,processor_thermal_device
intel_xhci_usb_role_switch    16384  0
cfg80211              712704  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
idma64                 20480  0
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
roles                  16384  1 intel_xhci_usb_role_switch
intel_soc_dts_iosf     20480  1 processor_thermal_device
virt_dma               20480  1 idma64
mei                   102400  3 mei_hdcp,mei_me
intel_pch_thermal      16384  0
typec                  45056  1 typec_ucsi
int3403_thermal        20480  0
int340x_thermal_zone    16384  2 int3403_thermal,processor_thermal_device
intel_hid              20480  0
int3400_thermal        20480  0
acpi_pad              184320  0
sparse_keymap          16384  2 intel_hid,dell_wmi
acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
mac_hid                16384  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  1
parport_pc             40960  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                53248  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               45056  1 ip_tables
autofs4                45056  2
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 53248  0
nvme                   49152  2
psmouse               151552  0
sdhci_pci              53248  0
cqhci                  28672  1 sdhci_pci
ahci                   40960  0
nvme_core             106496  4 nvme
sdhci                  65536  1 sdhci_pci
libahci                32768  1 ahci
i2c_hid                32768  0
wmi                    32768  4 dell_wmi,wmi_bmof,dell_smbios,dell_wmi_descriptor
hid                   126976  4 i2c_hid,usbhid,hid_multitouch,hid_generic
video                  49152  3 dell_wmi,dell_laptop,i915
```

8. I checked the bios set-up. Camera is enabled there. I tried disabling and then enabling again. But it didn't help.
9. My current kernel is 5.4.0-107-generic. Since the webcam used to work earlier, I have tried with some of the previous kernels 5.4.0-105,104,100,90,80,70,60,52 and with 5.3.0-62. But none of them works.
10. On typing`id` to check if I am a member of the video group gives me the following:

```
uid=1000(bsarma) gid=1000(bsarma) groups=1000(bsarma),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),116(lpadmin),126(sambashare)
```

`groups` on terminal gives me the following:

```
bsarma adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

At this point, it is not clear to me, if I am a member of the video group.

Comment: Hello. If it has been several months since it last worked there is a good chance you have had a kernel update. What kernel are you using?

Comment: it is 5.4.0-105-generic

Comment: OK. The original kernel that 18.04 shipped with was a 5.3. The kernel has been updated which in itself is not a bad thing. Once in a while for certain hardware a newer kernel is not the right one. When booting choose the Ubuntu Advanced and choose a lower kernel and see if the camera works again. Some times a newer kernel is needed but in your case since you said it worked and now it does not I would go for a lower.

Comment: okay thanks! I will try it and see.

Comment: I tried with the kernel 5.3.0-62-generic and the webcam still doesn't work.

Comment: I'd take a 20.04 live usb stick and try - just to make sure that your hardware didn't break. If you have a windows alongside, (dual boot) you might try this - just to rule out any hardware defects.

Comment: Thanks. I will try with 20.04. I don't have a windows alongside.

Comment: Are you a member of the `video` group? `id` will tell you.

Comment: Was that the next kernel down? I would not have jumped way back in time you said it was working a few months ago.

Comment: 5.3.0-62 is the very first kernel shown on `dpkg --list | grep linux-image`. After your comment, I have tried with 5.4.0-104, 100, 90, 80, 70, 60 and 52. None of them works.

Comment: @waltinator `id` gives me `uid=1000(bsarma) gid=1000(bsarma) groups=1000(bsarma),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),116(lpadmin),126(sambashare)` and `groups` gives me `bsarma adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare`  on terninal. Don't know, how can I know, if I am a member of the video group.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers (who have better answers). Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our way to help you improve your question. All facts about your system and problem should go in the Question with [edit].  You may click on any of these [edit] links to [edit] your question.

Comment: thanks for the guidelines.